# Domain of a two-variable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider function $f(x,y) = \frac{x}{y}^{\frac{x^2}{y-x}}$. I know the function is defined on $(x\geq0)\bigcap (y>0)\bigcap(x\neq y)$ which is the first quarter except $y=0$ and $x=y$. Can we find a wider range on which the function is defined?

Answer (score 1):

For nonzero $x$, the function is equivalent to

$$f(x,y)=e^{\frac{x^2}{y-x}\ln\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)}$$

$\ln$ is defined when its argument is positive, that is $\frac{x}{y}>0$. This occurs if $x$ and $y$ are both positive or both negative (with $x\neq y$), so yes.

**Edit**: As Ishraaq Parvez kindly pointed out in a comment, I forgot to mention that the points satisfying $x=y$ are forbidden. I've edited my post to include this.

Comment: Also excluding the points where $y=x$.

Comment: @IshraaqParvez ah yes, good point. Thanks for pointing that out!